# c++ bindings for libclang

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang, libclang

I'm aware of python bindings as well as original c lang written libclang, but I'm trying to use it in classrooms, and we teach c++. So if anyone is aware of c++ bindings, getting hands on it would be very helpful.

Ref - http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html

Comment: libtooling? http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's little purpose in using libclang from C++, since libclang is just a bad C wrapper on the Clang C++ API. If you need to use Clang from C++, just drop libclang and go straight to the source.